# Adding a Row to an HTML Table Using Jython

Tags: html, jython

So I have some HTML code that creates a table in an HTML file.  It has a header and an example row for what the data will contain.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'> 
p {margin: 0em 0 0em 0}
th {color: blue; text-align: left}
tr {color: black; text-align: left}
table {font-size: 25}
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black}
</style>
<meta content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'http-equiv='content-type'> 
<title>Test Results</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Test</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>DateTime</th>
  <th>Blank Lines</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>AreaStudyClimate</td>
  <td><font color='green'>PASSED</font></td>
  <td>20140707 11:38:37.473000</td>
  <td>[]</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

I simply want to add a row of data using jython.  How I have done it WORKS, but it seems pretty ugly.  I create a variable that concatenates the following html code:

```
row +="    <tr>\n" \
      "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
      "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
      "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
      "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
      "    </tr>\n"
```

The reason I set it as a variable is because I'm reading the original HTML code from the same file that I want to write to.  So how I have it set up, I don't "add" a row per say, but instead replace the previous code with code that contains an additional row.  I use a for loop to get to the location I want to add that information to (in my case, I waited until it reads /table, and then I insert it there - that puts it at the bottom of the table).  Here's the python code:

```
time = str(datetime.now()).replace("-","")
failed_lines = str(failed_fields).replace(",",".")
if len(failed_fields) == 0:
    status = "<font color='green'>PASSED</font>"
else:
    status = "<font color='red'>FAILED<font>"

file = open("C:/psi-test-automation/SikuliX Projects/ValueChecking.sikuli/TestResults.html", 'r+')
row = ""
for line in file.readlines():
    if "/table" in line:
        row +="    <tr>\n" \
        "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
        "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
        "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
        "      <td>%s</td>\n" \
        "    </tr>\n"        
    row+=line

newform = row % (form['title'], status, time, failed_lines)
file.close()
file = open("C:/psi-test-automation/SikuliX Projects/ValueChecking.sikuli/TestResults.html", 'w')
file.write(newform)
file.close()
```

I have the "status" variable contain color coding because I want it to be green if it passes or red if it fails.

The final issue I have is that, in order to replace the code, I have to reopen the file - in order to use readlines (at least, as far as I can see), it must be in read mode.  However, in order to clear the contents of the file, it seems to have to be in write mode (which I can't start off in because then it would clear the data I need to copy).  To solve this, I close the read version of the file, and after creating the new code, open it up again in write mode - I find it hard to believe this is the best way (f.truncate() didn't do anything either...).

So to summarize, I'm currently replacing previous HTML code with updated code containing an additional row; I want to use jython code to just add a row to an HTML table.

Sorry for such a long post, but there was a lot of information to put into it.

Comment: Can you use a templating engine such as Jinja2?

Comment: I'd prefer not to get any addons/modules.  I guess I should've clarified it's technically jython

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest different approach for logging. New test data could be added to txt or csv file witch would be just simple appending additional row. In the end of a test run, based on txt or csv file there could be new HTML file created (overwriting old HTML file anyway, or not). For creating basic log file I would recommend [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Comment: I'd need to edit the formatting, though, which you can't do it txt or csv.  I'm not quite sure how to convert it automatically.